# Wpf event not bubbling

Tags: c#, wpf, events

Here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="844.025" Width="678"  MouseUp="somethingClicked">
<Grid MouseUp="somethingClicked">
    <StackPanel MouseUp="somethingClicked" Margin="0,0,10,0">
    <Button x:Name="btnClickMe" Content="Click Me!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="101,22,0,0" MouseUp="somethingClicked"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="chkhandle" Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="241,28,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.588,1.188"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="lstEvents" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="604" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="416" Margin="29,66,0,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And here is the C# Code:

```
namespace WpfApplication4
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    protected int eventCounter = 0;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void somethingClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        eventCounter++;

        String message = "#" + eventCounter.ToString() + ":\r\n" +
            " Sender: " + sender.ToString() + ":\r\n" +
            " Source: " + e.Source + ":\r\n" +
            " Original Source: " + e.OriginalSource;

        lstEvents.Items.Add(message);
        e.Handled = (bool) chkhandle.IsChecked;

        if (e.Handled)
            lstEvents.Items.Add("Completed");   

    }
}
```

}

I have the following issues with this example:
1)The MouseUp event is not fired on clicking the button.
2)The event doesn't bubble up. Clicking somewhere on the form displays:

```
Sender:WpfApplication4.MainWindow:
Source:WpfApplication4.MainWindow:
Original Source: System.Windows.Controls.Border.
```

If I understand rightly, when button is clicked, first it should be executed at Window level (which it does now), then Grid, then stack and finally text label. Is the code wrong or is my understanding of the concept faulty?

Comment: I don't know why,but it's working for right click..

Comment: @Naren: Because when you click the left button is fires `Click` event, thus swallowing a mouse event (MouseUp, MouseDown, MouseLeftButtonDown). When you right-click, `Click` event does not fire.

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev Thanks..I never have noticed it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `The MouseUp event is not fired on clicking the button.`

Because the first fires is an event at the `Button.Click`, and when it works, it conflicts with the event `MouseUp`. Quote from [here](http://wpf.2000things.com/2012/10/04/661-buttonbase-click-event-vs-mouse-click-events/):

> ButtonBase inherits from UIElement, a Button will also have access to all of the mouse button events defined for UIElement. Because the Button does something in response to button presses, it swallows the bubbling events (e.g. MouseLeftButtonDown and MouseDown).  You can still detect these lower level button press events by adding handlers for the tunneling events (e.g. PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown and PreviewMouseDown).

Try to replace the `Button` on `Label`, and you'll get the desired result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Replacing button with label worked as expected. Still learning. I will work on building a calculator and hopefully it will be clear.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft wrote a very nice explanation [Routed Events Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806(v=vs.100).aspx)

[image]

exactly the same thing will happen with `MouseUp`and `PreviewMouseUp` events
in your case the  `e.Handled = (bool) chkhandle.IsChecked;` stops the routing of the event.

if you want to debug the events you can use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) it will illustrate very nicely which events happened on which objects and who handled them.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have bookmarked it. I'm finding this one concept a bit difficult. I have to keep revisiting it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try handling the PreviewMouseDown event instead. You can still
   attach that from XAML. In your handler
2. Attach the event handler in code instead. Use the signature of
       AddHandler

.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        Grid1.MouseUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Grid1_MouseUp);
}
private void Grid1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
        MessageBox.Show("Mouseup");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an override available to handle events, even though they were marked as handled.  It requires that you add your handler through code as the following:

```
MainWindow.AddHander(UIElement.MouseUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(button1_MouseUp), true);
```

That last parameter specifies whether you want to accept events that were handled already or not.  If you add that handler to your main window, you'll notice that the routed MouseUp events from your button are indeed bubbling up, (but their e.Handled indicates that they were already handled).