# How to make rotation in XAML of one element by clicking on another one?

Tags: xaml

I have such code (cut only part which is needed; this code is used as a UserControl):

```
<Grid>
        <Image x:Name="im" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="120" Width="120">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="0" CenterX="60" CenterY="60" />
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <Button x:Name="br" Content="Right" Width="55">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseUp">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="im" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" By="90" Duration="0:0:1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

I'd like to rotate image ("im") by 90 degrees by clicking the "br" button. This code doesn't work.
But if I use this code:

```
<Grid>
        <Image x:Name="im" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="120" Width="120">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="0" CenterX="60" CenterY="60" />
            </Image.RenderTransform>
            <Image.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseUp">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="im" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" By="90" Duration="0:0:1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Image.Triggers>
        </Image>
        <Button x:Name="br" Content="Right" Width="55">
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

rotation works (image is rotating by clicking on it). What's wrong with the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried the Button.Click Routed event instead of MouseUp. The reason for MouseUp not working for button is explained here: [Wpf event not bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327627/wpf-event-not-bubbling).

The code you provided will work on Right button click of mouse. On left button click of mouse, the Click event is swallowing up the Mouse events.

I tried the below code and it seems to work. I have used a dummy image as source.

```
   <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="im" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="120" Width="120" Source="..\Images\info.png">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="0" CenterX="60" CenterY="60" />
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <Button x:Name="br" Grid.Row="1" Content="Right" Width="55">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="im" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" By="90" Duration="0:0:1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

Let me know in case you need any more information.