# MenuItem in WPF only registers right click, but not left

Tags: c#, wpf

Being fairly new to C# and WPF, I'm currently designing a window and at the moment I'm working on the basic window logic to operate and function correctly. The problem I have is when a MenuItem is left clicked it does not register the left click, but will register a right click. The logic is programmatic.

WPF:

```
<Menu Grid.Row="0"
        Background="LightGray"
        Margin="0,40,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Height="20">
    <MenuItem Height="Auto"
              Width="Auto"
              Header="File">
      <MenuItem Header=""/>
      <Separator/>
      <MenuItem x:Name="closeWindowMenu" 
                Header="Close"
                MouseUp="button_MouseUp"/>
    </MenuItem>
  </Menu>
```

C#:

```
private void button_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  //MessageBox.Show(((FrameworkElement)e.Source).Name);
  //Minimize button
  if ((((FrameworkElement)e.Source).Name) == "miniWindow") 
  {
    this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;

    //Original Design
    miniWindow.Background = Brushes.Gray;
    miniWindow.FontSize = 15;
  }
  //Close button 'X' (This works for the 'X' but not for the MenuItem)
  else if ((((FrameworkElement)e.Source).Name) == "closeWindow" || 
           (((FrameworkElement)e.Source).Name) == "closeWindowMenu")
  {
    Close();
  }
}
```

I've tried using two different mouse and both of those had the exact same results. For the record, this same piece of code works if I was to press the 'X' to close the window.

Comment: You might find your answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327627/wpf-event-not-bubbling

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any reason why you are using the `MouseUp` event instead of the `Click` event?

Try using Click. In your XAML:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="closeWindowMenu" 
            Header="Close"
            Click="button_Click"/>
```

And in your C#:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  //MessageBox.Show(((FrameworkElement)e.Source).Name);
  //Minimize button
  if ((((FrameworkElement)e.Source).Name) == "miniWindow") 
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the `MouseUp` event is already consumed by the control and is not bubbled up. So your handler is never triggered. If you definitely need to rely on this event then you will have to subscribe to the tunnelled equivalent: `PreviewMouseUp`. Other then that your code will look exactly the same.

```
<MenuItem x:Name="closeWindowMenu" 
          Header="Close"
          PreviewMouseUp="button_PreviewMouseUp"/>
```

Edit:

You can check `MenuItem` source code [here](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/Net/Net/3@5@50727@3053/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/Orcas/SP/wpf/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/MenuItem@cs/1/MenuItem@cs). It already consumes `OnMouseLeftButtonUp` so that's probably why your code responds to the right click but not to the left click.